# Dice game giving one extra turn

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am writing a simple dice game, where two players throw two dices and summ up their scores untill one hits the total score of 100. The problem I am facing is, when one of the players hits 100, the game allows another throw, how do I stop it?

```
import random       
a=random.randint(1,6)
b=random.randint(1,6)
c=random.randint(1,6)
d=random.randint(1,6)
ta=0
tb=0
print("Vai vēlaties mest?")
y=input("y/n:")
if y == "y":
 print("Jūs uzmetāt:")
 print (a,b,"|", a+b+ta)

 print("Pretinieks uzmeta:")
 print (c,d,"|", c+d+tb)
else:
 print ("Jūs zaudējāt")
while ta<=100 and tb<=100:
 ta+=a+b
 tb+=c+d 
 a=random.randint(1,6)
 b=random.randint(1,6)
 c=random.randint(1,6)
 d=random.randint(1,6)
 print("Vai vēlaties mest?")
 y=input("y/n:")
 if y == "y":   
  print("Jūs uzmetāt:")
  print (a,b,"|", a+b+ta,)

  print("Pretinieks uzmeta:")
  print (c,d,"|", c+d+tb)
 if y=="n":
  print ("Jūs zaudējāt")
 elif ta>=100:
 print("Jūs uzvarējāt")
 elif tb>=100:
  print("Jūs zaudējāt")
```

And yes I know this can probably be written a lot shorter and better, but this is what is asked of us in school, so only the commands you see here are allowed

Comment: I would strongly suggest an indentation of 4 spaces to make the code more readable!

Answer (score 1):

Use `while ta < 100 and tb < 100:`.

Another issue is that you are computing new random values of `a`…`d` after updating `ta` and `tb`, but then adding these new values later in the same loop. This has the effect of always printing what ta and tb will be on the next pass, which will make it seem that you have gone past 100.

As a separate point, without looking into it too deeply, I suspect you can replace everything between `import random` and `while ta …` with `a = b = c = d = ta = tb = 0` and get the same behaviour.

Finally, you can shorten the random assignment thus:

```
(a, b, c, d) = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(4)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion on shortening the random assigment, I was looking for something like that. But, the ta<100 and tb<100 still give me one extra turn

Comment: I’ve updated my answer to cover why I think you’re overshooting 100.